# Linux: Allow www-data to mute/unmute sound

Tags: linux, alsa

To mute and unmute sound I successfully use the following command in the terminal (as root):

```
amixer -D pulse set Master 1+ toggle
```

But it's not working if I trigger this command via PHP (shell_exec) as user *www-data*.
I get the error:

```
ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused
amixer: Mixer attach pulse error: Connection refused
```

This probably has to do with user rights, but I can't figure out how to grant these rights to user *www-data*, can you help?

Additional info from *pactl info*:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pactl info
Server-Zeichenkette: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Bibliotheks-Protokollversion: 34
Server-Protokollversion: 34
ist lokal: ja
Client-Index: 32
Tile-Größe: 65496
Name des Benutzers: pi
Rechnername: raspberrypi
Name des Servers: pulseaudio
Version des Servers: 14.2
Standard-Abtastwert-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Standard-Kanal-Zuordnung: front-left,front-right
Standard-Ziel: alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB2.0_Device_20130100ph0-00.analog-stere                                     o
Standard-Quelle: alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB2.0_Device_20130100ph0-00.analog-ste                                     reo.monitor
Cookie: 249b:a636

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ stat /run/user/1000/pulse/native
 Datei: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
 Größe: 0               Blöcke: 0          EA Block: 4096   Socket
 Gerät: 20h/32d Inode: 33          Verknüpfungen: 1
Zugriff: (0666/srw-rw-rw-)  Uid: ( 1000/      pi)   Gid: ( 1000/      pi)
Zugriff: 2021-11-14 11:34:40.192044159 +0100
Modifiziert: 2021-11-12 15:33:34.489999995 +0100
Geändert: 2021-11-12 15:33:34.489999995 +0100
Geburt: -
```

Comment: Who is running the pulseaudio server? Where's the socket located at? For security reasons, I think it would be wiser to decouple the functionality anyway - have a deamon listening on a socket for messages from your php script and have your php script send notifications to that deamon, then that deamon is easier to configure and protect. Like rhasspy communicates via MQTT.

Comment: @KamilCuk Oh, I'll check that for you, but how can I get this info?

Comment: `pactl info` from the user that can conect. Then `stat /the/path/to/socket`

Comment: Interesting, I guess I'll will try to go with your suggestion @KamilCuk by using a deamon. I will have to do some research on that. Thank you. I've added the info from pactl info to the post anyway though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it with the help of Eli Billauer's tech blog:
http://billauer.co.il/blog/2014/01/pa-multiple-users/

For more details visit his blog post.

**In short, the steps are:**

**To do as the desktop’s user (in my case 'pi')**
copy /etc/pulse/default.pa into a file with the same name in the .pulse directory, that is

```
cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.pulse/
```

And then edit the file, adding the following line at the end:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1
```

At this point, restart the pulseaudio deamon,

```
$ pulseaudio -k
$ pulseaudio -D
```

**To do as "www-data" user**
Now switch to the second user (www-data),  and create a file named client.conf under that user’s .pulse subdirectory (I had to create that. in www-data's 'home' direction which is /var/www/)

```
$ echo "default-server = 127.0.0.1" > ~/.pulse/client.conf
```

Note that default.pa and client.conf are in completely different directories, each belonging to a different user!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Datei: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Zugriff: (0666/srw-rw-rw-)  Uid: ( 1000/      pi)   Gid: ( 1000/      pi)
```

Either way, you have to point your application to the correct path and give permission to access it.

I believe adding `www-data` user to `pi` group, and then executing `env PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH=/run/user/1000/pulse/native pamixer....` should do the trick. Actually, the socket is `rw-rw-rw-` anyway, so maybe you don't have to add the user to group anyway.

The other alternative is to open RDP to pulseaudio and connect from php to it.

Comment: So to give the application permission to access the path I would 'chmod' the folder/file for user www-data to have reading/writing rights, correct?

Comment: That would be one way, but the file is recreated on pulseaudio restart.

Comment: Ok, so I added user www-data to group pi and run the env command (added quotes to the path for it to work), but still get the same error. I will try your RDP idea,  maybe I will get it working with that.